# How to open Device from Google Chrome Emulator using WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, emulation

I have the following code,

```
[Binding]
public class Setup
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    public const int DefaultTimeOut = 10;

    public Setup(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public static IWebDriver Driver;

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void SetUpBrowser()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.EnableMobileEmulation("Apple iPhone 6");
        Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DefaultTimeOut);
    }
```

I want to be able to run the browser using Google Chrome's emulator, but unfortunately, I'm recieving the following error message: "Message: There is already an option for the mobileEmulation capability. Please use the instead. Parameter name: capabilityName"

It'd be even more beneficial if I could use this outside the SetUpBrowser method, e.g. within a method that runs later in my test, I was thinking possibly adding the above to ChromeOptions but I didn't have any success

The way in which I tried the above is:

```
[Binding]
public class Setup
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    public const int DefaultTimeOut = 10;

    public Setup(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public static IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void SetUpBrowser()
    {
        Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DefaultTimeOut);
    }
```

And the method in which I want to switch to the Mobile Emulator was:

```
    [Given(@"I am on the mobile website version")]
    public void GivenIAddAmOnTheMobileWebsiteVersion()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.EnableMobileEmulation("Apple iPhone 6");
        Cookie SetMobileCookie = new Cookie(VariableList.MobileCookieValue, "true");
        MobileCookie = VariableList.MobileCookieValue;
        _driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(SetMobileCookie);
        _driver.Click(ElementType.Id, VariableList.MemberLoginButton); //should be a new method
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change text to "iPhone 6"

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.EnableMobileEmulation("iPhone 6");
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

you have to match the EnableMobileEmulation with parameter on your chrome

go to developer mode > then click on mobile icon. on the top left you can find list of all available device name you can use.

for example if you want to use iphone x, your code should be like this

```
options.EnableMobileEmulation("iPhone X");
```

[image]